# safely remove a child with enterframe running

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, haxe

Whenever I try to remove an object/child with enterframe running I always get null reference error.
In my particular case, the setup is Battlefield contains a lot of Robot:

1. A child (Robot) dispatchEvent that it is destroyed
2. The parent container receives the event and starts removing the child by removeChild and remove the child from an array of Robots.
3. on enterframe, during a loop to move the robots around, sometimes I would get null reference, so I have to call if (robots[i] == null) continue;

How do you safely remove the child without sprinkling if robot is null all over my enterframe?

one idea I have is to have a list of robots to be removed inside the enterframe that checks whether there is a robot to be removed, and if there is, do the removal there instead of the callback on robot exploded event.

Comment: Can you post code?  How do you traverse your robots collection?  Do you keep an array or are you looping over children in the display list?

Comment: How do you traverse your robots collection?
it's just an array of robots

Do you keep an array or are you looping over children in the display list?
I keep the array because in the Battlefield container has other elements that are not Robot.

I will post the code later, i should probably mention that this is in Haxe however, I encounter this problem in other flash based framework such as Corona SDK (using lua)

Comment: You make robot manager class called Robots to manage all the Robot class instances. Keep it modular and in good OOP fashion encapsulated.

Comment: @The_asMan  it won't solve the problem of whenever there is an event being dispatched, it will still encounter null reference

Comment: Not if the manager handles all the robot instances. At that point it becomes trivial. the enterFrame loop never have a need to know if a robot is null it just needs to call a function in the manager class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I normally do:

1) Have an `active` bool in the object getting updated. When you call your `destroy()` function or whatever to cleanup, set `active` to `false`. In the `update()` function, make a check at the start. if `active` is `false`, quit out.

2) Have a `removeFromUpdate` property that's set to true when you want to delete your object. In your UpdateManager (or whichever calls the `update()` on your objects) do something like this:

```
private function _update():void
{
    // update our objects
    var remove:Boolean = false;
    var len:int = this.m_objects.length;
    for( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        this.m_objects[i].update();
        if( this.m_objects[i].removeFromUpdate )
            remove = true;
    }

    // if we don't have anything to remove, quit
    if( !remove )
        return;

    // we have something to remove, so traverse the array
    // backwards (so we don't have index problems)
    for( i = len - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        if( this.m_objects[i].removeFromUpdate )
        {
            // you can optionally call the object's destroy() function
            // here

            // splice the array
            this.m_objects.splice( i, 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

That pretty much works for me. You can optionally have the object's `update()` function return true if it should be removed if you want to save on a parameter

Comment: i have thought of using flags, to it feels rather dirty because that means all of the moving objects need to have that and the update will have to check for it.  Is this a common practice to avoid such problem from happening? or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: your problem is that an object could get deleted during an update. It's only really common when you have a lot of objects getting updated in a list. I don't think I've ever had an object get deleted in the middle of that object's updated, unless it was specifically called. This is pretty much how it's done in most engines I've seen (there could very well be another solution, this one is just the easiest)

Comment: having, for example, an `active` boolean (which you check just before calling `update()`) also lets you do other things with your game, namely make it easier to pause entire groups or specific objects. That's pretty common

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one in haXe the `Array` actually has a `remove`-method. You can use that to remove the robots for good. The method also reports of its success, so your code would look something like:

```
if (robotsArray.remove(explodedRobot)) 
    robotsLayer.removeChild(explodedRobot)
```

Please note however, the call to remove on the `Array` should not occur while it is being iterated over, or you most certainly will get weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I can not post comments yet, so have to do it this way.

Two things I can think off:
You say you remove the child from Robots list. So it seems strange that you encounter null values in the list; unless the remove implementation has a mistake?

Is it possible that inside the ENTER_FRAME while going trough the robots, robot instances get removed? If so, it might help if you go trough the list starting at the last index. If an instance gets removed, it will not change the items at lower index.

Something like:

```
for(var index: int = list.length; index--; ) doSomething(list[index]);
```

Comment: hmm removing from the end sounds interesting, im gonna try that after I get home.

so what happens is, while looping the robots, if the event is dispatched it will introduce race condition where the robot at that index is removed so it returns null when access its index